# "No implementation for org.sonatype.ossindex.maven.common.ComponentReportAssistant was bound" error when using Maven plugin for Sonatype OSS Index

Tags: maven, sonarqube, maven-plugin, static-analysis

I try to use the Apache Maven plugin for Sonatype OSS Index (https://sonatype.github.io/ossindex-maven/maven-plugin/) to audit my project dependencies using Sonatype OSS Index.

When I launch the command :

```
mvn org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:audit-aggregate -f pom.xml
```

I have the following console error :

```
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.sonatype.ossindex.maven.common.ComponentReportAssistant was bound.
[ERROR] while locating org.sonatype.ossindex.maven.plugin.AuditAggregateMojo
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.1.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6d9bf996]
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.sonatype.ossindex.maven:ossindex-maven-plugin:3.1.0:audit-aggregate)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error happened when you launch the command with a Maven version prior to the needed version (3.1+).

In my case, it was Maven 3.0.5.